# Bumblebee with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ModulePath empty

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a time. I just upgraded my xubuntu to 16.04 and my nvidia drivers broke again. So, as usual, I had to uninstall all nvidia drivers (I was using nvidia-352-updates) along with bumblebee. So I did it, and then I did the same process again (little observation here: I'm using now nvidia-361-updates):

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-361-updates -y && sudo apt-get install bumblebee`

Ok, everything set up and I headed up to the
[/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf](http://pastebin.com/5dTms2Ce) to point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the `XorgModulePath` entry to the correct nvidia folder, that in my case is `nvidia-361`. After that I just restarted the computer and tried to run:

`optirun glxinfo`

And I received the answer:

`[ranu@ranu-laptop ~]$ optirun glxinfo
[  515.027004] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU, secondary X is not active.
[  515.027105] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.`

I was astonished, then I ran a more verbose one (`optirun -vv -debug glxinfo`):

`[  334.856357] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  334.856840] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia-361
[  334.857253] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[  334.857290] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  334.857298] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  334.857305] [DEBUG] X display: ebug
[  334.857311] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[  334.857319] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  334.857326] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[  334.857341] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  334.857380] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[  334.857400] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[  334.870268] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl
[  337.882765] [INFO]Response: No, secondary X is not active.
[  337.882803] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU, secondary X is not active.
[  337.882817] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  337.882869] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  337.882887] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.`

Weird, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty even though it's filled with information in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. So I then ran:

`bumblebeed -vv -debug`

And received the output:

`[  782.329141] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)
[  782.329201] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)
[  782.329236] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  782.329655] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia-361
[  782.329684] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia-361'
[  782.329850] [DEBUG]successfully loaded bbswitch
[  782.329866] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.
[  782.329879] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  782.329899] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  782.329919] [DEBUG] X display: ebug
[  782.329938] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[  782.329957] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  782.329977] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
[  782.329995] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.DRIVER
[  782.330017] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
[  782.330043] [DEBUG] ModulePath: 
[  782.330063] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
[  782.330084] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
[  782.330104] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
[  782.330123] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia-361
[  782.330142] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia-361
[  782.330163] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1
[  782.330418] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 3094.
[  782.330566] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[  782.333919] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[  782.333969] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.
[  782.334023] [ERROR]Cannot open or write pidfile /var/run/bumblebeed.pid.`

Ok, this is even weirder, the configuration test has passed but `ModulePath` is empty as well and I don't know the why, on top of that it can't write the pidfile, permission issue?

Comment: Ok, don't mind the pidfile problem, I was not running as sudo, so it couldn't write anything and the process (bumblebeed) was already running.

Comment: I noticed that you have set `Driver=nvidia-361` in your config file (`[bumblebeed]` section). Maybe you should try with `Driver=nvidia`

Comment: You are right about that @adonis! Never thought of it, although another error has appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the `Driver` entry at the bumblebee config file should be `nvidia` and not `nvidia-361`, although the bumblebeed says that the configuration test has passed as seen before:

`[  782.333969] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.`